# Jquery google map directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to Let users enter their postcode to which it gets directions to the given postcode my original code is

```
 <div class="map-block">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('images'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('shop_title'); ?>" />

            <div class="map-bottom">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('shop_title'); ?></h3>
                <a class="findToggle" href="javascript:void(0)">How to find us</a>
                <p>Our Address: <?php the_sub_field('address');?></p>
                <form class="map-form">
                    <input type="text" class="user-postcode" placeholder="Please enter your postcode">
                    <a class="btn get_directions"    href="javascript:void(0)">Find Us</a>              
                </form>             
            </div>

        </div>




    $('.map-block').on('click', '.get_directions', function () {
            var val = $('.user-postcode').val();
            if (val.trim() == '' || val === null) {val = "Enter your location"; }
            window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + val + "&daddr=CF23 9AF");
    });
```

Which works for only one div, my divs are being generated by WordPress so i tried setting a different id to each one and then using jquery to get value for each one but for some reason its not working and i cannot see why here is my code for multiple divs.

```
 <div class="map-block" id="map-<?php echo $i++ ;?>">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('images'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('shop_title'); ?>" />

            <div class="map-bottom">
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('shop_title'); ?></h3>
                <a class="findToggle" href="javascript:void(0)">How to find us</a>
                <p>Our Address: <?php the_sub_field('address');?></p>
                <form class="map-form">
                    <input type="text" class="user-postcode" placeholder="Please enter your postcode">
                    <a class="btn get_directions"    href="javascript:void(0)">Find Us</a>              
                </form>             
            </div>

        </div>




 var mapid = $('.map-block').attr('id');
    $(' + mapid + ').on('click', '.get_directions', function () {
            var val = $('.user-postcode').val();
            if (val.trim() == '' || val === null) {val = "Enter your location"; }
            window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + val + "&daddr=CF23 9AF");
    });
```

Comment: Please define "not working." Are exceptions being thrown? What results are you expecting versus the results you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find the postcode in the `div` with `$(this)`:

```
$('.map-block').on('click', '.get_directions', function () {
    var val = $(this).parent().find('.user-postcode').val();
    if (val.trim() == '' || val === null) {
        val = "Enter your location"; 
    }
    window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + val + "&daddr=CF23 9AF");
});
```

Comment: `this` in the provided context refers to `.get_directions` which doesn't wrap `.user-postcode` so `$(this).find('.user-postcode')` will never resolve to an element.